# Video and data streaming visualization with Flask

Tags: python, flask, streaming

I am trying to create a dashboard with **flask** where I can see video streaming and other data (strings) on the same html page. Just to make things easier, for the moment I stream from a set of `jpg` images in the folder  `"static/imgs/"`, and the telemetry is the name of the each `jpg` file. The problem is that the telemetry data does not show on `index.html`: i.e I only see the video stream and a blank where the telemetry text is expected. 
The files are: `app.py`, `index.html`, `tel.html`

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import os
from time import time, sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

#load images from folder
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dir_imgs = "static/imgs/"

        self.frames_name = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir (self.dir_imgs))]
        self.current_idx = 0

    def get_frame(self):
        idx = self.current_idx 
        self.current_idx = idx + 1
        if self.current_idx >= len(self.frames_name):
            self.current_idx = 0
        sleep(0.02)
        #return an image
        return open(self.dir_imgs+self.frames_name[idx], 'rb').read()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html' )

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        idx = camera.current_idx
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: static/imgs/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


class Telemetry():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame_name = None

telemetry = Telemetry()

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    camera = Camera()
    feed_gen = gen(camera)
    telemetry.frame_name = camera.frames_name[camera.current_idx]

    return Response(feed_gen,
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/tel')
    def tel():
        frame_name = telemetry.frame_name
        return render_template("tel.html", fname=frame_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True) #start the webserver
```

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
<br>
{% include "tel.html" %}
  </body>
</html>
```

### tel.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1> Frame Name: {{ fname }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean, after "Frame Name:", you expect to see the value of `fname` ?

Comment: yes, that's correct! I would expect index.html to show: [ Image] and below [Frame Name: img_126.jpg] for instance, but instead I see: [Image ] and [Frame Name: ]